# Getting UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE while handling SSL/TLS in python

Tags: python, ssl

I'm writing a custom web proxy which will work with `FoxyProxy` addon in Firefox. I generated some self signed certificates and I think I'm loading them how they should plus I have added the `min` and `max` versions of `TLS` and it still looks to have problems.

```
import socket
import signal
import ssl
import traceback
import select
import sys
import threading

def start_server(host, port):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(4096)
    print(f"Server listening on {host}:{port}")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Connection established with {client_address}")

        # Create a new thread to handle the connection
        t = threading.Thread(target=handle_connection, args=(client_socket,))
        t.start()

def handle_connection(client_socket):
    try:
        data = read_full_request(client_socket)  # Read full HTTP request from the client

        if not data:
            # No data received, close the connection gracefully
            client_socket.close()
            return

        # Handle HTTP/HTTPS based on the destination port
        dest_host, dest_port = extract_host_port(data)

        print(f"h:{dest_host}, p:{dest_port}")

        if dest_port == 443:
            handle_https(client_socket, data)
        else:
            handle_http(client_socket, data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred during connection handling: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()

    finally:
        # Close the client socket
        client_socket.close()

def create_https_context():
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile="./keys/bundle.pem")
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile="./keys/cert.pem",
                            keyfile="./keys/privatekey.pem")

    # Explicitly set the minimum and maximum TLS versions to TLSv1.3
    context.min_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3
    context.max_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3

    return context



def read_full_request(client_socket):
    buffer = b""
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(4096)
        buffer += data
        if b"\r\n\r\n" in buffer:
            break
    return buffer

def handle_https(client_socket, data):
    try:
        # Handle HTTPS connections (TLS handshake)
        dest_host, dest_port = extract_host_port(data)
        print(f"Received HTTPS CONNECT request: {dest_host}:{dest_port}")

        # Create a client socket and wrap it using the client-side SSL context
        context = create_https_context()
        client_ssl_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_hostname=dest_host)

        # Forward the CONNECT request to the destination server
        forward(dest_host, dest_port, data, client_ssl_socket)

        # After forwarding the CONNECT request, establish a tunnel
        tunnel_established = False
        while not tunnel_established:
            server_data = client_ssl_socket.recv(4096)
            forward(dest_host, dest_port, server_data, client_ssl_socket)
            tunnel_established = b"\r\n\r\n" in server_data

        print("HTTPS tunnel established.")

        # Once the tunnel is established, forward the encrypted data without interpretation
        while True:
            server_data = client_ssl_socket.recv(4096)
            if not server_data:
                break
            forward(dest_host, dest_port, server_data, client_ssl_socket)

    except ssl.SSLError as e:
        print(f"SSL Error occurred during HTTPS handling: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()

    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()


def handle_http(client_socket, data):
    try:
        # Handle HTTP connections
        http_request = data
        while b"\r\n\r\n" not in http_request:
            data = client_socket.recv(4096)
            http_request += data

        print(f"Received data over HTTP:\n{http_request.decode('utf-8')}")

        dest_host, dest_port = extract_host_port(http_request)  # Pass data directly
        forward(dest_host, dest_port, http_request, None)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred during HTTP handling: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()

def extract_host_port(http_request):
    host, port = None, None
    lines = http_request.split(b"\r\n")
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(b"Host: "):
            host_port = line[6:]

            if b":" in host_port:
                host, port = host_port.split(b":")
                port = int(port)
            else:
                host = host_port
                port = 80
            break
    return host, port

def forward(hosts, ports, datas, context):
    # Forward the packet to the extracted destination
    forward_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    if ports == 443:
        forward_socket = context.wrap_socket(forward_socket, server_hostname=hosts)
    forward_socket.connect((hosts, ports))
    forward_socket.sendall(datas)
    forward_socket.close()
    print("Packet forwarded successfully.")

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("Server terminated by Ctrl+C")
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = 8080
    start_server(HOST, PORT)
```

I get this error and I have explored different ways but I have failed. Could someone lend me a hand?

The error:

```
h:b'push.services.mozilla.com', p:443
Received HTTPS CONNECT request: b'push.services.mozilla.com':443
SSL Error occurred during HTTPS handling: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:997)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "burplike.py", line 83, in handle_https
    client_ssl_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_hostname=dest_host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:997)
```

Comment: I don't think that you properly handle the CONNECT request. It should a) not be forwarded to the final server and b) you need to send an answer to the request and c) you should not extract the target from the Host header but from the CONNECT line. Also upgrading the socket to SSL should only be done if you want to intercept the traffic (i.e.SSL man in the middle).

Comment: But isn't the `three-way handshake` done in `context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_hostname=dest_host)` line? Well I think I kinda am doing SSL MiTM now thinking about it but even that I'm not doing right!

Comment: The current title is very vague; revising it to be more narrowly focused on the specific error would help prevent people with completely different/unrelated TLS issues from ending up here.

Comment: Thank for advice I will narrow it down.